# Override FontFamily

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have set a FontFamily in my ResourceDictionary

```xml
<FontFamily x:Key="RegularFontFamily">Segoe UI Regular</FontFamily>
```

and I have set a Theme for Buttons, CHeckBoxes, Labels, etc, where I want to adapt that FontFamily and make it overridable

```xml
<FontFamily x:Key="ComboBoxFontFamily">This is where I want to reference the RegularFontFamily</FontFamily>
```

And with this approach, I can override the RegularFontFamily within the `app.xaml`:

```xml
<FontFamily x:Key="RegularFontFamily">Arial</FontFamily>
```

or, if I only want to change the FontFamily for the ComboBox, I can override the 'ComboBoxFontFamily'.

So how am I able to reference the `RegularFontFamily` from within the Theme?

Comment: Something like that? <StaticResource x:Key="ComboBoxFontFamily" ResourceKey="RegularFontFamily"/>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a `FontFamily` from another `FontFamily` and, also, you cannot change the family name of a `FontFamily` after it has been constructed.

The solution to your issue is either to set the themed font directly:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ComboBoxFontFamily">Segoe UI Regular</FontFamily>
```

...or to *programmatically* get the "RegularFontFamily" resource and replace your "ComboBoxFontFamily" resource with it at runtime.

But there is no kind of binding option or similar available that you can use in XAML.